# Woocommerce - Cambiar el 'carousel' por defecto de los productos

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Me explico mejor:

Cuando entras a un producto, se muestran las imagenes del mismo a modos slider o carrusel. Me gustaría cambiar el que viene por defecto, ya que debajo de la imagen principal salen las miniaturas, y no me gusta el diseño.

Me gustaría añadir algo mas simple como el 'carousel' de Bootstrap.

Conoceis algun plugin para hacer esto? O alguna otra manera?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mi aporte seria el siguiente, que quede fijo el slider de las imagenes, pero desaparezcan las imagenes pequeñas ("thumbnail").

Desde *function.php* de tu tema:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

Te comparto un link que encontre, con varias opciones, en ingles:
https://wpsites.net/web-design/remove-woocommerce-single-thumbnail-images-from-product-details-page/

Espero te sirva!